# Integral of Error Function

Tags: integration, approximation, gaussian-integral

Is there a way to approximate this integral with a constant expressed in terms of $\delta$

$$\int_{0}^{1} e^{-\left(\frac{x^2}{2\delta^2 }\right)} dx$$

Thanks

Comment: This integral uses the error function. Do you know how to approximate the error function?

Comment: Taylor series would probably help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\frac{x}{\delta}=y$

Now your integral becomes

$$\delta \sqrt{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\delta}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy=\delta \sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(\frac{1}{\delta})-\Phi(0)]=\delta \sqrt{2\pi}[\Phi(\frac{1}{\delta})-\frac{1}{2}]$$

The values of $\Phi(x)$ are tabulated everywhere...it's the CDF of the Standard Gaussian

To approximate this integral a lot of methods are available. A pretty Statistical method is the ["Importance Sampling"](https://statweb.stanford.edu/%7Eowen/mc/Ch-var-is.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much